# Не получается вывести сумму

Tags: c, указатели, динамические-массивы

Написать программу, выделив под массив динамически память. Обращаться к элементам массива необходимо используя указатель.
В одномерном массиве, состоящем из n вещественных элементов, вычислить сумму элементов массива, расположенных между первым и вторым отрицательными элементами.

Всегда выводит 0. Не могу понять в чём ошибка. Спасибо.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf ("Введите кол-во элементов массива\n");
    int n;
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    int *ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf ("Введите %d элемент массива\n", i + 1);
        scanf ("%d", ptr + i);
    }

    int ind_neg1;
    int ind_neg2;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (ptr + i < 0){
            ind_neg1 = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = ind_neg1 + 1; i < n; i++){
        if (ptr + i < 0){
            ind_neg2 = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = ind_neg1 + 1; i < ind_neg2; i++) {
        sum = sum + (*ptr + i);
    }

    printf ("Сумма между 1 и 2 отрицаиельными = %d", sum);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` у вас - указатель на массив. `ptr+i` - на его `i`-й элемент.
**Указатель**! Не элемент!

Сам элемент - надо разыменовывать. Или написать `ptr[i]`, или `*(ptr+i)`.